# Create a row with character and numeric

Tags: r, row

I want to create a single with NA values, 0 values and characters as shown below:

```
newrow = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "GPP", numeric(0), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, numeric(0), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

However, the zero values are transformed in NA values in the output.

```
[1] NA    NA    NA    NA    "GPP" NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: `numeric(0)` is not the same as `0`.  You either want `0` or `numeric(1)`, but keep in mind that R does not allow these different types in the same atomic vector.  They will all be coerced to character

Comment: Alright. So Any ways I can achieve what I want?

Comment: To mix arbitrary objects, use a `list`. Type `?list` for details.

Comment: Thanks Frank. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Frank:

```
newrow = list(NA, NA, NA, NA, "GPP", numeric(1), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, numeric(1), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```